# FirebaseJobDispatcher or AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, firebase-job-dispatcher

To make things clear from the start, here is the app desired flow :

precise date with day/hour/minutes is selected
  -> a new `Job` is created and scheduled with `FirebaseJobDispatcher` -> the `job` is triggered exactly at the right date, and runs periodically (say period is 1-2 sec) a code that will define if the `job` needs to run again. If it does not need to run again, end it definitely, else, re-run it. Also, the `job` should have a "duration time" (usually 60sec) that will end it whatever happens in the `job`.

So far I'm confused about three things :

- The Trigger window seems completely unreliable and runs the `job` approximately when it wants
- Should I use `FirebaseJobDispatcher#setRecurring` or `jobFinished(job, true);` inside the service ?
- Sometimes, `setRecurring(boolean)` is set to `false`, as well as `jobFinished(job, false);`, and the job still runs again

Maybe I should use `AlarmManager` instead ? But it seemed like the new way was  `FirebaseJobDispatche`, so I don't know.

Here is some code

Service:

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            simulateBackgroundTask(job);
        }
    }).start();

    return true;
}

private void simulateBackgroundTask(JobParameters job) {
    try {

        Log.d(TAG, "completeJob: " + "jobStarted --------------------");

        //request server or db
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Log.d(TAG, "completeJob: " + "jobFinished --------------------");

        //shoudRunAgain is from the result of the request
        if(shouldRunAgain)
            jobFinished(job, true);
        else
            jobFinished(job, false);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    return false;
}
```

Activity

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(App.getContext()));

    Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setService(SearchService.class)
            .setTag("SearchService")
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(startDate,endDate))
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
```

Any advices or solutions are welcomed, thank you

Comment: Doze or any other battery saving mode make any sort of cron job in Android to be executed solely when a maintenance cycle is started, this will also happen with alarms. At least with the FirebaseJobDispatcher you can add constraints. The problem with using Alarm and the JobScheduler is maintaining to blocks of code for different API levels.

Comment: So there are no ways to be sure the task will run exactly at the right time ?

Comment: No, and that is correct and what Android developers deserve (we all). That is the way to respect the battery of the user. And this happened because Android developers abuse from everything, broadcast receivers, services, alarms. There have being already 2 changes for services and now in Oreo it had tobe restricted even more! Because developers make eternal sticky service for pointless tasks